# Intuition behind the naming of horizontal and vertical tangent spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles

Let $\pi: P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. For any point $x \in M$, let $p \in P_x$ be a point in the fiber $P_x = \pi^{-1}(x)$.

In Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he defines:

> The vertical tangent space $V_p$ of the total space $P$ in the point $p$ is the tangent space $T_p(P_x)$ to the fiber.

and

> A horizontal tangent space in $p \in P$ is a subspace $H_p$ of $T_pP$ complementary to the vertical tangent space $V_p$, so that $$T_pP = V_p \oplus H_p.$$

I am trying to develop some geometric intuition for these spaces but I am having trouble visualizing them. Is there any reason these tangent spaces are called vertical and horizontal?

On the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_and_horizontal_bundles) they state:

> The name is motivated by low-dimensional examples like the trivial line bundle over a circle, which is sometimes depicted as a vertical cylinder projecting to a horizontal circle.

In this case the fibers are vertical, but what about the tangent spaces to the fibers are vertical or the complement horizontal?

Comment: If you're convinced that the distribution tangent to the fibers should be called "vertical", then there is nothing deeper about it: "horizontal" is any complement to "vertical". Remember, we don't have a metric to provide us with a notion of angle here, so "horizontal" doesn't need to mean "orthogonal to vertical".

Comment: To beat a dead horse, a fiber bundle generalizes a global product $X\times F$, and we typically “draw” $X$ as horizontal and $F$ as vertical. The tangent space of the fiber (as in the case of a nontrivial bundle) is still a well-defined vertical subspace of the tangent space of the total space.